# AngularJS ng:form -- How to change the behaviour of 'enter' key

Tags: angularjs

Referring to the [Angular docs for ngForm directive](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3aform):

> If a form has only one input field then hitting enter in this field
>   triggers form submit (ngSubmit)
>
> if a form has has 2+ input fields and
>   no buttons or input[type=submit] then hitting enter doesn't trigger
>   submit
>
> if a form has one or more input fields and one or more buttons
>   or input[type=submit] then hitting enter in any of the input fields
>   will trigger the click handler on the *first* button or
>   input[type=submit] (ngClick) and a submit handler on the enclosing
>   form (ngSubmit)

In my form, I  have a [Bootstrap button-radio](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#buttons) followed by a `button[type=submit]` However, when one presses the 'enter' key from within an input box, the first "button-radio" gets clicked instead of the `button[type=submit]`

I know, as per the doc this is supposed to happen (*first* button or input[type=submit]), but is there any way to change this behaviour?

Comment: Could you post a code example?

Comment: I'm not being able to reproduce this on Plunker. But it's happening in my app. Wonder what's the difference... Strange!

Answer (score 0):

How about putting a hidden button on top of the form which has binding to do the `submit`?